# Negative match set of strings in regexp_substr

Tags: oracle11g, regex-negation

I want to match all characters in a string until I hit one of the following substrings:

```
'='
'+%'
'-%'
```

I had no problem negating a set of single characters (i.e. [^=+-]), and I can positively match the strings with

```
(=|\+%|-%)
```

but I can't seem to figure out the syntax for negating the set.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't do it with REGEXP_SUBSTR alone but here is one option:

```
with temp as
(
  select 'TEST1=TEST1' test1 from dual union all
  select 'TEST2+%TEST2' test1 from dual union all
  select 'TEST3+TEST3' test1 from dual union all
  select 'TEST4-%TEST4' test1 from dual union all
  select 'TEST5-TEST5' test1 from dual
)

  SELECT test1,
         CASE
           WHEN REGEXP_INSTR(test1, '+%|=|-%') = 0 THEN test1
           ELSE REGEXP_REPLACE(SUBSTR(test1, 1, REGEXP_INSTR(test1, '-%|+%|=')), '[-=+%]')
           END
         result

  FROM temp
```